# Qt set default value for style-sheet property

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets

I have an application where users can modify the Qt stylesheets. I want to set default value for some property in case the user-provided stylesheet does not define them, e.g.

```cpp
// user provided style sheet for the whole app
qApp->setStyleSheet("file://user-provided.qss");

// default value for my button
myButton->setStyleSheet("color: red"); // I'd like this to apply only if the stylesheet does not provide it
```

The way Qt cascading works, setting the stylesheet on the widget override anything from the application style-sheet, even if the specifier on the application stylesheet are stronger.

I tried using `QPalette`, or different foreground roles with custom color in the `.ui`, but nothing worked. Unless I use `setStyleSheet`, the foreground color does not change (as expected since `QPalette` is ignored when a stylesheet is used).

Is there a way to have a default value in case a property is missing from the application stylesheet? Basically reverse the cascading effect of Qt?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the "default" stylesheet with all needed style rules on the QApplication instance (for the whole application) and the "user" stylesheet on the top level widget.
So the stylesheet set on the top level widgets extends and overrides the application stylesheet.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QWidget widget;

    auto label_1 = new QLabel(&widget);
    label_1->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("label_1"));
    label_1->setText("Label 1");
    auto label_2 = new QLabel(&widget);
    label_2->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("label_2"));
    label_2->setText("Label 2");

    auto layout = new QVBoxLayout(&widget);
    layout->addWidget(label_1);
    layout->addWidget(label_2);

    widget.setLayout(layout);

    QString defaultStyle = "#label_1{color:red};"; // default for label_1
    QString userStyle = "#label_2{color:blue};"; // rule for label_1 is missing

    app.setStyleSheet(defaultStyle); // set the default stylesheet on the application
    widget.setStyleSheet(userStyle); // set the user stylesheet on the top level widget

    widget.show(); // label 1 has blue color and label 2 has red color

    return app.exec();
}
```